# Views Bulk Operations Modify entity values on one form

Tags: views

I am trying to use VBO to update order status on entities.
When using "Modify entity values" it shows 'Modify entity values' on vbo dropdown and then it redirects to a page with dropdown with all the options.

How to make it all on one form so I could check rows and then select (eg.) an order status option?

Is there any module or do I have to go programmatically through this journey?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom action in Rules that sets the entity value to the one you want rather than prompting for the value.  Then activate that action in your VBO view.

You can make new rules components at `mysite/admin/config/workflow/rules/components/add`